# what are all the tables in "Aspnetdb" database used for?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, database

i was reading about how to do memebership,roles and profiles in asp.net and they all seem to be very easy,but there is one thing, which all the tutorials and books i have seem to forget to talk about.

the data base generated by asp.net has some tables, which i have no idea what they are used for.

i was woundering if anyone could provide me with an explanation of what each table in the "aspnetdb" is used for

thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Explaining it here would be a bit lengthy.  Take a look at MSDN's documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478948.aspx).

There are 8 parts to the article in total.  Each one describes what each table is used for from both a high level and a more detailed level.

Comment: Glad to hear it.  Feel free to accept this answer by clicking the Check mark image in the top left corner of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's used to house the data used by the default membership/roles/profiles provider.  You could figure out the details (it's not a complicated schema) but good design principles would say you should treat it like a black box and not touch it directly - only touch it via the membership/role/profile APIs.  Don't rely on Microsoft keeping their internal implementation details the same in the future.